# How to sort menu elements and how to add URLs for these elements?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, menu, documentation, navigation, orchardcms

Getting started with Orchard 1.5.1, I follow the tutorial provided here:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Navigation-and-menus

and found that the Interface in the tutorial is different from that of 1.5.1 version, and I could not find how to sort menu elements or how to add URLs for these elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigation has changed since version 1.5:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-1-5-Release-Notes#Navigationmodule

You can sort items with drag & drop…

Comment: And please how to attrib URLs to Menu elements ?

Comment: Enable "Check on a menu" in the Page or Blog configuration.  This applies to all Content Type with the Navigation Part (of course you can add it to any Content Type). In the Navigation page you can add four types of elements…

Comment: since version 1.5: Navigation -> Custom Link pane -> Add button